# An interesting error during processing wxWidgets event

Tags: python, events, wxwidgets

I'm coding some Windows app using wxWidgets library and I've stuck on something interesting:

```
    def HandleDblclick (self, event):
        self.ItemActivation (event.GetItem ())

    def HandleKeydown (self, event):
        keyc = event.GetKeyCode ()
        if keyc == 13:
            self.ItemActivation (event.GetItem ())
        elif keyc == 32:
            self.ItemSelection (event.GetItem ())
        self.sbar.SetStatusText (str (keyc) + " was pressed.")

    def HandleRclick (self, event):
        self.ItemSelection (event.GetItem ())
```

(yes, it's Python). ItemActivation () and ItemSelection () do all the dirty work. But only when I press the mouse button. When I enter a key, I get the following output:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode\wx\_controls.py", line 5315, in GetItemPyData
return _controls_.TreeCtrl_GetItemPyData(*args, **kwargs)
wx._core.PyAssertionError: C++ assertion "param" failed at ..\..\src\msw\treectrl.cpp(1083) in wxTreeCtrl::SetItemData(): failed to change tree items data
```

I'm trying to code a TreeCtrl. What's funny, nevertheless the error the tree expands (enter key), but item selsction (space) doesn't work at all.

What's going on and why? I think that wxWidgets try to handle the event twice, once with their default handler and twice with mine. But if I'm correct, how to disable default keyboard event processing for wx.TreeCtrl?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why dont you use `wx.WXK_RETURN` ?  and try adding `wx.PROCESS_ENTER` to the style argument on the tree control maybe? (note, im not sure either will work... but maybe..)

Comment: can you post a complete(but short!) code example ? including app setup and frame layouts. .. thats the only way anyone is gonna actually try and duplicate your problem :)

Comment: I'm afraid you ask for the impossible. I hadn't code the file I/O yet and I have whole definition of tree data in ca 100 lines (there are actually 8 tree widgets swapped in place given the circumstances... I think I should rethink the idea). If you're really into it, maybe send me your mail at troton1927_at_o2.pl and I'll feed you with the code.

Comment: you should almost certainly rethink the idea ... make a smaller example with one tree widget and post the whole code ...  you can post it somewhere else and link it if you would rather ... i would assume you can make an example in less the 40 lines of code...

Comment: Negative. I assigned little frame space for my bonsai widget so I can load only one level of children at time. Thus I have to store the tree structure in my own dictionary. Thus I'd have to dump all 100+ lines of code at minimum, if I had to fulfill your wish. I don't know does Stack Overflow will stand this. Permission to dump?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it's a *bad* idea to try to handle keyboard in any native control yourself. Just remove your `EVT_KEY_DOWN` handler entirely and handle `EVT_TREE_ITEM_ACTIVATED` instead. This is guaranteed to work on all platforms, unlike stealing events from the native control which may really want to have it on its own.

Second, the error about `SetItemData()` failure doesn't seem to have anything to do with the code you showed because it doesn't call this function at all. So you must not be showing us all of the relevant parts.

Answer (score 0):

That's why the error is interesting. I DO NOT set any data item; I actually try to RECEIVE it. The line that stinks is the first one in both of my dirtywork functions:

```
ikey = self.GetPyData (item)
```

I really don't know what's going on and why wxWidgets engine tries to assign some data to item. I asked Uncle Google for this error, but I got no usable info.

Thanks for remark on keyboard handling.